# Trying to run 'npm run dev' on a Windows local machine with files in a Mapped Drive - W:\

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to run **'npm run dev'** on a Windows machine with my files in a folder on a Mapped Drive W:\

I store my projects on a NAS server for testing before uploading them to a server.

**'npm init svelte@next www'** works OK.

**'npm install'**  works OK

**'npm run dev'** When I run this it errors - UNC path issue below - should this work??

I have tried various terminals and checked file permissions.

Do the files need to be on the same physical machine as the node is running for the dev environment to work?

Any help appreciated - Many Thanks

```
W:\SVELTE3\www>npm run dev

www@0.0.1 dev
svelte-kit dev

Pre-bundling dependencies:
  svelte
  svelte/store
  svelte/animate
  svelte/easing
  svelte/internal
  (...and 2 more)
  
(this will be run only when your dependencies or config have changed)

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/NAS-SERVER/SVELTE3/www/node_modules/svelte/index.mjs'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at optimizeDeps (W:\SVELTE3\www\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-f5552faa.js:56586:42)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOptimize (W:\SVELTE3\www\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-f5552faa.js:60549:48)
    at async Server.httpServer.listen (W:\SVELTE3\www\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-f5552faa.js:60565:21)
```

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, at least.  Did you still want to troubleshoot or look for workarounds, or did you just decide to move the project off a mapped drive?

Comment: Hi Hasip - I did decide to move the project onto a new local drive and set up an automatic backup of the drive to give me the same redundancy as my NAS! Thank you for your reply.